# AppleScript : multiple condition

Tags: variables, applescript, conditional-statements

I need multiple condition to be true to run my script

```
set var1 to "variable 1 is here"
set var2 to "variable 2 is here"


if var1 = "variable 1 is here"  and var2 "variable 2 is here" then
    set var1 to "true"
end if
```

This is not working though, I guess AppleScript don't allow this.

I was thinking then to do something like this :

```
set score to 0
set var1 to "variable 1 is here"
set var2 to "variable 2 is here"

if var1 = "variable 1 is here" then
    set score to score + 1
end if

if var2 = "variable 2 is here" then
    set score to score + 1
end if

if score = 2 then
...
```

Is there anything simpler that this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the `=` after the var2

```
if var1 = "variable 1 is here" and var2 = "variable 2 is here" then
```